# Validating User input when joint together?

Tags: python-3.x

In my code, it is supposed validate the user input that is a number , 8 digits and is in my text file. Before I had the validation separate so it would accept any 8 digit number which I obviously do not want , so when i combined them , i keep on getting syntax error. (Line 5 )

```
GTIN=''
items=[]
while len(items) < int(itemsneeded):
            GTIN=(input('Please enter all GTIN-8 for all items'))
            if GTIN.isdigit() and len(GTIN)==8 and in open('read_it.txt').read():
                Num0=int(GTIN[0])*3
                Num1=int(GTIN[1])
                Num2=int(GTIN[2])*3
                Num3=int(GTIN[3])
                Num4=int(GTIN[4])*3
                Num5=int(GTIN[5])
                Num6=int(GTIN[6])*3
                Num7=int(GTIN[7])
                total2=(Num0+Num1+Num2+Num3+Num4+Num5+Num6+Num7)
                if total2 % 10 == 0:
                    print(GTIN)
                items.append(GTIN)
            else:
                print("Product Not Found")
print(items)
```

Comment: `and in open('read_it.txt').read()` looks like you are missing what should be in `open('read_it.txt').read()` for the condition to evaluate `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if GTIN.isdigit() and len(GTIN)==8 and in open('read_it.txt').read():
```

Use

```
if GTIN.isdigit() and len(GTIN)==8 and GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read():
```

You have to put

```
...GTIN in open('read_it.txt').read()
```

Comment: What a silly mistake , thank you very much , works great :) (I'll accept gotta wait 5 min)